# how to typecast Child to Parent object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I have an `ASP.Net Core 2.1 C#` application.

This is how my DTOs looks like.

```
public class Movie
{
  public int Id { get; set;}

  public bool IsSpecial {get; set;}

  public IEnumerable<Ticket> Tickets{ get; set;}
}
```

Tickets (Base Class)

```
 public class Ticket
 {
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public string Name { get; set;}

   public decimal price { get; set;}
 }
```

TicketsSpecial (Child/Derived Class)

```
 public class TicketsSpecial : Ticket
 {
    public string SpecialProp1 { get; set;}

    public string SpecialProp2 { get; set;}

 }
```

WebAPI Controller

```
public class MovieController : ControllerBase
{

  public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Movie movie)
  {
      if(movie.IsSpecial)
      {
         var tickets = movie.Tickets;
         movie.Tickets = new List<TicketsSpecial>(); 
        movie.Tickets = tickets;
         SomeMethod(movie.Tickets);// throws run time error
         movie.Tickets = tickets;
      }
  }

  private bool SomeMethod(IEnumerable<TicketSpecial> tickets)
  {
  }
}
```

RTE

> > Unable to cast object of type 
> >     'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Ticket]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TicketSpecial]'

Also,the extra properties of TicketSpecial is unavailable as it's not present in Ticket class.

so I tried vice-versa

```
public class Movie
{
  public int Id { get; set;}

  public IEnumerable<TicketSpecial> Tickets{ get; set;}
}
```

Going this way, I get the values of extra fields ie. TicketSpecial props. But again while typecasting it throws the error.

```
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Move movie)
  {
      if(!movie.IsSpecial)
      {
         var tickets = movie.Tickets;
         movie.Tickets = new List<Ticket>();//throws Compile time error 

      }
  }
```

> But this throws the error as CS0266   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. 
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

***I want to address this with #2 (second way) as I would have the extra props value in case `move.IsSpecial` is true***

How to handle this typecasting?
Thanks!

Comment: I tried this `movie.Tickets = new List<TicketsSpecial>();//throws Compile time error ` with dotnetfiddle, no error here.  _(with the `public IEnumerable<TicketSpecial> Tickets{ get; set;}`)_

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, sorry for typo, please check now Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to pass an `IEnumerable<Ticket>` to something expecting `IEnumerable<TicketSpecial>`, and of course you are not allowed to do that.

Comment: What do you expect `IEnumerable<TicketSpecial> myList = new List<Ticket>()` to do?

Comment: @HimBromBeere myList when typecasted to Ticket type it should not have the extra properties as SpecialProp1, SpecialProp2

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik yes throws the error `Error CS1929 'IEnumerable<Ticket>' does not contain a definition for 'AsEnumerable'`

Answer (score 0):

Must prepare a list of special tickets from movie.Tickets and pass to the consumer

```
var specialTickets = new List<TicketsSpecial>();
specialTickets.AddRange(movie.Tickets.OfType<TicketsSpecial>());
SomeMethod(specialTickets);
```

In your example, the second assignment assigned the tickets property back to the original one which is a list of ticket, not special ticket.

Comment: how would get the extra properties values that are present in the `TicketSpecial (SpecialProp1, SpecialProp2 & so on)`

Comment: @Kgn-web You need to write a custom ModelBinder to tell the MVC framework to construct the correct instance of the SpecialsTicket. I suggest you have a look at the MS document here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.0#polymorphic-model-binding

Comment: doing so `specialTickets` doesn't have item of movie.Tickets

Comment: the doc recommends the ModelBinder is not suitable for RESTAPIs & I have the APIs

Comment: RESTAPI and MVC are one. If you give it a try, it should work

Comment: @Kgn-web If you are in charge of DTO, I would suggest having 2 tickets in the Movie class. `NormalTickets` and `SpecialTickets` Then you do not have to deal with Model Binder. Instead of checking `movie.IsSpecial`, just check `movie.SpecialTickets != null && movie.SpecialTickets.Count > 0`. This approach makes the design explicitly, easy to understand

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382676/automapper-error-mapping-types-mapping-types-ienumerable1-ienumerable1?noredirect=1#comment103122079_58382676

Comment: I updated the DTO & Model (NoSql) as above link. Can you please check & suggest? Thanks!