# how to instantiate the collection/class based on a property in C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Below are my DTOs.

```
public class Movie
{
  public int Id {get; set;}

  public string Name {get; set;}

  public IEnumerable<BasicTicket> Tickets { get; set;}

}
```

Ther are multiple types of Ticket of type BasicTicket

```
public class BasicTicket
{
   public int Id {get; set;}

   public bool IsSpecial { get; set;}

   public bool IsDicount{get; set;}
   public decimal Price { get; set;}
}
```

## 1

```
public class SpecialTicket : BasicTicket
{
  public string SpecialProp1 {get; set;} //n such properties where n could be the range of 2 to 10
}
```

## 2

```
public class DiscountTicket : BasicTicket
{
  public string SomeProp1 {get; set;} //n such properties where n could be the range of 2 to 10
}
```

& so on

Now basis on the boolean property present in the Movie, the collection of Ticket to be initialized accordingly.

One such try:-

```
public IEnumerable<BasicTicket> Tickets { 
     get { return Tickets;} 
     set 
     { 
       if(this.IsSpecial)
       {
           value = new List<SpecialTicket >();
       }
       else
       {
           value = new List<BasicTicket>();
       }
     }
```

But doing so, when I debug I don't see any error message, simply debugging stops

In Actually these all are DTO for APIs. So also tried this.

```
WebAPI Controller

public class MovieController : ControllerBase
{

  public IActionResult Post([FromBody]Movie movie)
  {
      if(movie.IsSpecial)
      {
         var tickets = movie.Tickets;
         movie.Tickets = new List<SpecialTicket>(); 
          movie.Tickets = tickets; // Throws error or doesn't get the values of the props present in TicketSpecial
         movie.Tickets = tickets;
      }
  }

  private bool SomeMethod(IEnumerable<TicketSpecial> tickets)
  {
  }
}
```

- [how to typecast Child to Parent object in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58372592/how-to-typecast-child-to-parent-object-in-c-sharp/58373119?noredirect=1#comment103096473_58373119)

Also, wanted to know if adding properties to BasicTicket (if n= 2 or 3)on fly using ExpandoObject would be good or not?

I think there would be some design pattern that would rightly address this object creational but didn't find anything yet.

Thanks!

Comment: You should revise your question, you have properties like movie.IsSpecial in your code, that doesn't exists. Stuff like TicketSpecial and SpecialTicket, things called type "Ticket" that doesn't exist, etc.

Comment: You are using Entity where there is a mapping between the classes and the database.  The classes have to be mapped to the existing table in the database and if you add or change the classes or the database the mapping needed to be updated.  Writing will also fail if there is no connection to the database.  Compiling checks if the classes match the mapping table, but doesn't verify the database matches the mapping.  You will get run time errors when reading/writing to the database if the mapping is not correct.

Comment: Your getter for `Tickets` is recursive... I'm assuming you don't want that. Use a backing field.

Answer (score 1):

Your property implementation is erroneous. This implementation would lead to a StackOverflowException in the `get` accessor (probably this is why your debugger stops without showing you any error) and nop in the `set` accessor.

The correct way to implement a property with a backing field is:

```
private IEnumerable<Ticket> _tickets;

public IEnumerable<Ticket> Tickets 
{ 
    get { return _tickets;} 
    set 
    { 
       if(this.IsSpecial)
       {
           _tickets = new List<TicketSpecial>(value.Cast<TicketSpecial>());
       }
       else
       {
           _tickets = new List<Ticket>(value.Cast<Ticket>());
       }
    }
}
```

More on properties with backing fields: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties#properties-with-backing-fields

Comment: `_tickets = new List<TicketSpecial>(value); ` this is throwing Compile time error

Comment: `CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BasicTicket>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TicketSpecial>'  `

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed a cast in the List construction. I edited my answer.

Comment: Doing so, throws the run time error as  `Unable to cast object of type 'BasicTicket' to type 'SpecialTicket'.`

Comment: That's why you are assigning a collection of `BasicTicket` to the `Tickets` property (without converting them to `SpecialTicket`). At this point I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: BasicTicket is Parent class, SpecialTicket is Child class of BasicTicket

Comment: So you cannot cast a base class to its derived type (`BasicTicket` to `SpecialTicket`) without an explicit conversion.