# Automapper - Error mapping types. Mapping types: IEnumerable`1 -> IEnumerable`1 System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[TicketTO, app.DTO

Tags: c#, automapper

I have an `ASP.Net Core C#` application & using `AutoMapper`

DTO

```
public class MovieTO
{
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public IEnumerable<TicketTO> Tickets { get; set;}
}


public class TicketTO
{
   public string Prop1{ get; set;}
   public string Prop2{ get; set;}
   public string Prop3{ get; set;}
   public string Prop4{ get; set;}
}
```

Domain Entity

```
public class Movie
{
   public int Id { get; set;}

   public IEnumerable<BasicTicket> Tickets { get; set;}
}

 public class BasicTicket
{

}

 public class RegularTicket : BasicTicket
{
   public string Prop1{ get; set;}
   public string Prop2{ get; set;}
}

 public class SpecialTicket : BasicTicket
{
   public string Prop3{ get; set;}
   public string Prop4{ get; set;}
}
```

AutoMapper Configuration

```
 public class AppObjectsMapper
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public ObjectsMapper()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {

            cfg.CreateMap<TicketTO, RegularTicket>();
            cfg.CreateMap<TicketTO, SpecialTicket>();

            cfg.CreateMap<MovieTO, Movie()

        });
        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
    }


    public Movie MapToEntity(MovieTO movie)
    {

        if(movie.IsSpecial)
        {
            //#Line1
            _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TicketTO>, IEnumerable<SpecialTicket>>(movie.Tickets); 
        }
        else
        {
             //#Line2
            _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TicketTO>, IEnumerable<RegularTicket>>(movie.Tickets);
        }
        return _mapper.Map<MovieTO, Movie>(eventDetail);
    }

       }
```

When the mapper is called at #line1 or #line2, it throws the below run time error.

> Error mapping types. Mapping types: 
>   IEnumerable`1 -> IEnumerable`1
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[TicketTO, app.DTO, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] -> 
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Domain.SpecialTicket, myapp.domain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

How to typecast/map this ?

Thanks!

Comment: Not directly related to your error but what's the point of this: `IEnumerable<BasicTicket>` and `BasicTicket`? If you think you can shove both types of tickets into `IEnumerable<BasicTicket>` and read them out, it's not possible. This could be related to the issue but only by design.

Comment: Actually I read more of your code and my comment above is now directly related to the issue because of what you're doing in the method `MapToEntity`.

Comment: Call `AssertConfigurationIsValid`. And look at the full error message.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, Please note I have NoSql in Db (Model - Movie)

Answer (score 3):

Actually your are missing some of the configuration here which the exception actually clearly says.
So just read the exception and add the mapping that is missing like:

```
            cfg.CreateMap<TicketTO, BasicTicket>();
```

That should work.
Best regards
Robert